# Access JSON's object values to send them to another servlet or jsp

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, dom-events

I am new to using Facebook app environment. I am developing a small application. I am trying to use some social data in my project to check some conditions.
I don't know if I am accessing the JSON object returned by FB in the right way but here is my problem.

I want to send firstname to another jsp or a servlet from the current file. So, I created jsp variables and tried to assign the value of 'name' in response object obtained from Facebook.

When trying to print the firstname at the end of the jsp file, the firstname outputs empty. How can I use name and gender values in the object and send it to another jsp file or a servlet file?

Banging my head to find a solution. Someone please help!

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Facebook authentication usage</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <%! String firstname="";
        String lastname="";
        String middlename="lynne";

    %>



  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                                        // init the FB JS SDK
                                        FB.init({
                                        appId      : '532238706811106', // App ID from the App Dashboard
                                        //channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
                                        status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
                                        cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
                                        frictionlessRequests : true,
                                        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?

                                            });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                                            if (response.status === 'connected') 
                                            {

                                                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                                                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                                                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed        
                                                // request, and the time the access token 
                                                // and signed request each expire   
                                                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                                                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                                                 FB.api('/me', function(response) 
                                                            {
                                                                console.log(response); 
                                                                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                                                                 firstname=firstname+response.name;
                                                                 lastname=lastname+response.last_name;
                                                                 document.write(response.name+middlename);
                                                            });
                                            } 
                                            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
                                            {
                                                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                                                // but has not authenticated your app
                                                var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
                                              oauth_url += '?client_id=532238706811106'; //Your Client ID
                                              oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + 'https://apps.facebook.com/newjsp'; //Send them here if they're not logged in
                                              //oauth_url += '&scope=user_about_me,email,user_location,user_photos,publish_actions,user_birthday,user_likes';

                                              window.top.location = oauth_url;

                                            } 
                                            else 
                                            {
                                                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.

                                                window.top.location ='https://www.facebook.com/index.php';
                                            }
                        });

  };
  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
  (function(d, debug)
          {
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
                ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
            }(document, /*debug*/ false));


</script>
  <h1>this is a sample to test facebook authentication
        Welcome <%=firstname+""+lastname+middlename%></h1>

        <%out.print(firstname+""+lastname+""+middlename); %>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you set `firstname` to `""` but never change it from that value.

In your JavaScript code, `firstname=firstname+response.name;` does not set the String variable previously defined in your Java code. Instead, it sets a new variable that can only be seen by your JavaScript code.

Your Java code is run on the server-side, whereas JavaScript is run on the client-side. They're two completely different programs, executed at different times in completely different locations. For reasons such as this, it is not recommended to write both client- and server-side code in the same file.

As for a solution to your problem, I would suggest either seeking out a Java API for Facebook,  so that you can use it before your JSP is rendered, or, that you access the data returned from FB exclusively in JavaScript code. It may also be a good idea to read up on the differences between Java, JavaScript, server-, and client-side code.